# Javascript (or jquery) to get every image tag of a textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, tags, textarea

So suppose I have a textarea with a value of this:

```
<p>..random content..</p>
<img src="myimage1.jpg" />
<p>..random content..</p>
<img src="myimage2.png" />
<p>..random content..</p>
```

I want to check every img tag occurences and store the src in an array. Something like this:

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = // the result of the checking of the textarea
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}
```

How do I achieve this?

**SOLVED**

by appending it to another hidden div, something like this:

```
  $('#hiddenContent').append $('textarea[name=content]').val()   $img
= $('#hiddenContent').find('img')   $("#hiddenContent > img").each (i, ele) ->
    html = '<div class="image">
                <img src="' + $(ele).attr('src') + '" class="thumbnail" width="100" title="Click to remove" />
                <p>Image location: <b>' + $(ele).attr('src') + '</b> (copy <b>bolded</b> text to use on your content)</p>
                <p><small>click image to remove</small></p>
                </div>'
    $('.contentImages').append html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSrc(textarea) {
    var temporaryElement = document.createElement('div');

    temporaryElement.innerHTML = textarea.value;

    var images = temporaryElement.getElementsByTagName('img');

    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        output.push(images[i].src);
    }

    return output;
}

console.log(getSrc(document.getElementById('textarea')));
```

Updated!

Comment: Only INSIDE the textarea man, means if a textarea has a value of this: <img src="http://127.0.0.7/uploads/images/20150222-54e9a561cb65d.jpg" height="68" width="99"><br><br>test<br>&nbsp;te<br><br>stas<br>d<br><br><img src="http://127.0.0.7/uploads/images/20150222-54e9a59a42ef6.jpg"><br>

I only need the src of those, omitting the other

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `querySelectorAll()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

For example using [lodash unescape](https://lodash.com/docs#unescape)

```
<textarea id="content">
  <p>..random content..</p>
  <img src="myimage1.jpg" />
  <p>..random content..</p>
  <img src="myimage2.png" />
  <p>..random content..</p>
</textarea>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.3.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
function img_find(id) {

  var dom = document.getElementById(id);

  var e = document.createElement('div');

  e.innerHTML = _.unescape(dom.innerHTML); // Or use regex to replace &lt; to < and &gt; to >

  var imgs = e.querySelectorAll('img');

  var srcCollection = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    srcCollection.push(imgs[i].src);
  }

  return srcCollection;
}

img_find('content'); // ["myimage1.jpg", "myimage2.jpg"]
</script>
```

Comment: Not gonna work, it will also select elements OUTSIDE of textarea, and I have tried using it to select only textarea with document.getElementsById and combine it with with querySelectorAll but it returns nothing (tested with Mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do, using regular expressions:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ewh8qe0t/1/

```
function img_find() {
  var imgs = '<p>..random content..</p><img src="myimage1.jpg" /><p>..random content..</p><img src="myimage2.png" /><p>..random content..</p>';
  var regex=/src="([A-z]+\d*\.[A-z]{3})"/g;
  var imgSrcs = [], found;
  while (found = regex.exec(imgs)) {
    imgSrcs.push(found[0].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g,''));
  }
  return imgSrcs;
}
alert(img_find());
```